# How to add delay of X duration in Flutter App using Shimmer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am working on the Flutter app in which I want to display the loading option for 5 seconds and after 5 seconds it will display "No result Found".

### CODE

```
Widget Loading(){
 return Center(
  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
  baseColor: Colors.blueAccent,
  highlightColor: Colors.red,
  child:Text("Loading...",style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
      fontSize: 50),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
  period: Duration(seconds: 2),

  ),

 );
}

/// Use of Loading() in flutter pages

 body: (Details == null||Details.isEmpty)?
      Loading()
      : new SizedBox(.............)

// In this case, if "Details" has some data it automatically displays on-screen else, continuously loading(), I want after 5 seconds it displays "No Data Found"
```

Does anyone know how to add Timer/Duration/Delay in the above code ?, So that after 5 seconds Message will display on the screen "No data found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for this. Here is an example:

This is the future function for FutureBuilder. In this function you can build your own logic.

```
Future<bool> _future = Future<bool>.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 5),
    () {
      //do something here
      return true;
    },
  );
```

And this the FutureBuilder should look like

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data ? SizedBox(.............) : Text("No data found");
        } else {
          return Loading();
        }
      },
    )
```